# Page Pre-Loader Stuck In a Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have implemented a pre-loader on my webpage and it works! The only issue is the main content appears and then pre-loader pops back in and it loops like this indefinitely!

I know what the issue is but I can figure out how else I would do it. The issue is the

```
window.open("index.html", "_self");
```

this keeps reloading the index page which in turn reloads the preloader... Any help would be great!

HTML:

```
<body class="index-page">
<div id="overlay">
    <div class="preload-text">Loading. Please wait...</div>
    <div class="loader-frame">
        <div class="loader1"></div>
        <div class="loader2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
Body content below
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var preload = document.getElementById("overlay")
  var loading = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(frame, 64);

  function frame() {
    if(loading == 100) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      window.open("index.html", "_self");
    } else {
      loading = loading + 1;
      if(loading == 90) {
        preload.style.animation = "fadeout 1s ease";
      }
    }
  }

});
```

CSS:

```
#overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top0: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.preload-text {
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 150px auto 50px auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.loader-frame {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.loader1, .loader2 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.loader1 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-top: 5px solid purple;
  border-bottom: 5px solid purple;
  animation: clockwisespin 2s linear 3;
}

.loader2 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  top: 5px; left: 5px;
  animation: anticlockwisespin 2s linear 3;
}

@keyframes clockwisespin {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes anticlockwisespin {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {opacity: 1;}
  to {opacity: 0;}
}
```

Comment: Why are you reloading with window.open ? Once the time is out, just remove the overlay element.

Comment: I tried adding $(#overlay).css('display', 'none'); but this didnt work?

Comment: `$("#overlay").css('display', 'none');` with quotes, and remove the window.open()

Comment: Also, and I don't know if this is just a first step, but as a preloader is not very useful, it just waits some time. You should wait for actual content to load, otherwise some users will have a useless wait and others will still see the page with some content not loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys really appreciate it. @mikepa88 how would I incorporate waiting for the content to actually load? (that was my goal really)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var preload = document.getElementById("overlay")
  var loading = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(frame, 64);

  function frame() {
    if(loading == 100) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      $("#overlay").css('display', 'none');
    } else {
      loading = loading + 1;
      if(loading == 90) {
        preload.style.animation = "fadeout 1s ease";
      }
    }
  }

});
```

To wait for content, that depends on the type of content. For images, create a DOM image element in js, without putting it into the document. Then on the element load event, add to a counter that, when it's full, you know everything is loaded.
Kinda like that:

```
var imagesToLoad = ["path/to/image/1", "path/to/image/2", ...];
var contentNotLoaded = imagesToLoad.length;

for(var i = 0; i < imagesToLoad.length; i++){
    var image = document.createElement("IMG");
    image.load = function(){
      contentLoaded++;
      if(contentNotLoaded == 0) $("#overlay").css('display', 'none');
    }
    image.src = imagesToLoad[i];
}
```

For other content, it should work as well with the .load event, the trick is to set the load event before filling the content (in the image, assigning the src)